# SupportMapFragment Instead of MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I want to make an android application that uses Google Maps for Android v2.

I can show a map. I can even navigate and zoom. But, when I want to search for more operations to make, I can't find any.

I want this application to work on API level 8 and above. So, I used `SupportMapFragment`. I heard that, if I want to make my application to work on API level 8 and above, I have to use `SupporMapFragment`.

I found examples about `MapFragment`s, but unfortunately, not about `SupportMapFragment`.

I want to make these operations work in my application, however, they're using `MapFragment`:

[One](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html)

[Two](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-working-with-google-maps/)

Is there a way of doing things like, "add marker", "show my current location", and "take position of the point that I clicked"? (using `SupportMapFragment`, of course. )

Thank you very much already.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way of doing things like, "add marker", "show my current location", and "take position of the point that I clicked"? (using SupportMapFragment, of course. )

Yes.

Step #1: Add the Android Support package to your app.

Step #2: Have your activities inherit from `FragmentActivity` from the Android Support package.

Step #3: Change all `MapFragment` references (Java code and layout XML resources) to `SupportMapFragment`.

And you're done.

All of [my Maps V2 samples](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2) use `SupportMapFragment`, in conjunction with ActionBarSherlock (which is why you will see `SherlockFragmentActivity` as opposed to `FragmentActivity`.