# Adding a custom view (linear layout) to the top of a Support Map Fragment is failing

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments, supportmapfragment

I was working on a project and by following these instructions

([How to add buttons at top of map fragment API v2 layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694119/how-to-add-buttons-at-top-of-map-fragment-api-v2-layout))

I succeeded on adding components on the top of Map Fragment (Not the Support Map Fragment).  After that, I made a change to my code and by following these steps

([SupportMapFragment Instead of MapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693975/supportmapfragment-instead-of-mapfragment))

I changed my Map Fragment to Support Map Fragment. I didn't change anything from my map xml, besides

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

to

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

but when I ran my app my linear layout doesn't show on the Map anymore.
I tried changing from `FrameLayout` to `RelativeLayout` and adding some properties but it seems like it's still overlapping my `LinearLayout`.

Is there anything missing or in the wrong place?

PS. In the XML Graphical Layout view I can see the linear layout is correctly positioned on the Map.

XML Graphical Layout: http://j52.imgup.net/Imagen156161.png
Screencap of running app: http://i87.imgup.net/Imagen171ef6.png

Here is my current MapFragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/box"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_noborder_background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_marker_inactive" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtOrigen"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:hint="Origen"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" >
                    </TextView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_marker_inactive" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDestino"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:hint="Destino"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" >
                    </TextView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_blue_background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:text="Ruta"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                android:textColor="@color/white" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

activity_main.xml : My fragments container XML

```html
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!--
         As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
    -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!--
         android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead.
    -->
    <!--
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container.
    -->

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

From MainActivity.java, onNavigationDrawerItemSelected method where I create MapFragment

```
@Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager;
        switch (position) {
        default:
        case 0:
            fragment = MapFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            onSectionAttached(position + 1);
            break;
        }
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();

    }
```

MapFragment.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment  {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        private static View rootView;
        LocationManager locationManager;
        static GoogleMap map;

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
         */
        public static SupportMapFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public MapFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (rootView != null) {
                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
                if (parent != null)
                    parent.removeView(rootView);
            }

            try {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mapa, container,
                        false);
            }catch(Exception e){

            }

            // Location Service
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                    Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Inicializacion del mapa
            map = getMapFragment().getMap();
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(
                    ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
        private SupportMapFragment getMapFragment() {
            FragmentManager fm = null;

            // Log.d(TAG, "sdk: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
            // Log.d(TAG, "release: " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                // Log.d(TAG, "using getFragmentManager");
                fm = getFragmentManager();
            } else {
                // Log.d(TAG, "using getChildFragmentManager");
                fm = getChildFragmentManager();
            }

            return (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your activity, keep a reference to your linear layout

```
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
```

Then after the fragment is added to the layout with fragment transaction, bring your linear layout to front by doing

```
root.bringToFront();
```

Comment: In my onCreateView method I just added this line but it didn't work :(
 LinearLayout box = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.box);
 box.bringToFront();

When I was using MapFragment instead of SupportMapFragment it worked fine, but I haven't found any similar issues in other posts so far.

Answer (score 0):

Into your xml file

```
<fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

should be

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

because you initiate into the navigator drawer :

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();
```

but there is not id = to container.

Comment: Sorry, just edited my post adding my fragments' container XML (activity_main.xml). This line is replacing my main activity container with my map fragment: fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();